# Comparing a boolean value before setting it

Tags: c#, comparison, boolean

In C#, when setting a boolean variable's value to `false` *only* when it is `true`, should I check if it is `true` before setting it or just set it?

Assuming the variable is `true` 50% of the time, checking it makes sense since a comparison is faster. If the variable is `true` most of the time, should I just skip the comparison?

### Which is the better practice?

**Method 1, checking first:**

```
if (bVariable)
    bVariable = false;
```

or **Method 2, Just setting it:**

```
bVariable = false;
```

Under which conditions is **method 2** preferred, if ever?

Comment: Premature optimization. IMO useless optimization.

Comment: You don't know that. If the first priority is readability, then checking first might be easier to understand in the context.

Comment: In this scenario and 99.9% of others like it, faster is irrelevant.  Just set it to false as long as you don't need to perform any other conditional logic.

Comment: I guess the answer depends on a lot of factors, including the processor itself (pipelining, the cost of a missed branch prediction, caching, etc.). Did you try to benchmark this? I also assume that this will be premature (and unnecessary) optimization in your case, but I do think that the question is interesting from a (purely) scientific point of view.

Comment: It's a variable. So I **do** know it. If it was a property with possible side-effects, it would be a another story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What makes you think that the comparison is faster?  If the code you were writing was done in a C compiler, the IF statement would be split into at least two instructions -- a comparison/branching instruction and a "set" instruction on a single bit on a single word.

The "set" would compile to a single instruction.  Your "optimization" could possibly make your program run slower, and would cause your program to be less readable.  Just set the variable and don't try to overthink little things.

**CPUs aren't like databases.  You don't pay a high penalty for data modifications.**  You pay high penalties for making trips to main memory and for branching (if statements).  Branches cost performance because [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) CPUs actually start executing instructions *after* the branch before the branch instructions even make their decision!  (I know, that statement is somewhat mind-blowing).  But what that means is that the CPU has to spend resources "[guessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)" what the outcome of your IF statement is going to be.  If it guesses wrong, it has to "throw away" the results of all instructions that it guessed would be executed after the branch and try again.  It's bad.  It's why branches are expensive.

The moral of this particular story is not that you should never optimize, but that you should **never optimize without completely understanding the implications of your optimization**.  In this case, had you gone with Option 1, you could possibly end up with a slower app which is less readable to boot.

Actually, if you're really interested in this sort of thing, you should **definitely** pick up a copy of [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670).  It's full of discussions about this sort of thing, and is brilliantly written.

Comment: I've heard good things about Code Complete and will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't complicate life. Just set it. It's actually more expensive to check first, anyway, since you now have to slurp the existing value from RAM (or cache) before sending back a new value.

(With thanks to Colin Mackay...) Testing first also incurs pipeline stall penalties due to branch mis-predictions.

Comment: There was a question commented originally by FreshCode that has now been deleted. The question was why if statements are more expensive. My answer: if statements imply a jump operation in the processor. Jump operations mean the processor has to empty its pipeline of upcoming instructions to jump to the new set of instructions. (As I understand it, I'm not a processor expert)

Comment: Because you may have to the drag the old value out of RAM, which would stall the CPU for hundreds of cycles, whereas just setting the value will usually go straight to L1 cache with minimal latency.

Comment: Checking first means the value isn't always changed. The frequency of changes depend on the most likely value of the variable. Let's say in my case `bVariable` is rarely true then setting the value seems wasteful. I concur that in 99% of cases this will be premature optimisation, but what if it has to be done for each record in a _huge_ set of data that spans multiple pages?

Comment: @Marcelo: I'm not as knowledgeable on CPU caching, but why would just setting the value be less overhead than checking it? Wouldn't setting the value be just as intensive, if not more?

Comment: @FreshCode: You seem determined to conclude that testing first is better, so you should just write the code and see for yourself. Who knows? Maybe you'll prove the established wisdom wrong.

Comment: @Marcelo: Intuition tells me checking first is better, but I wouldn't have asked if I trusted my intuition :). I don't have time to test it properly, so I'd like to know the best practice, which should take into account working with huge sets of data.

Comment: As others have said, you are prematurely optimising. And often that leads to slower solutions because of the way the underlying architecture works is not always intuitive. Processor pipelining, for example, is great for speeding up the way the processor handles instructions but jump operations mean the pipline is full of instructions that can't be used because the flow has moved elsewhere.

Comment: The jump operation explanation makes sense. Perhaps add that to your answer, Marcelo?

Comment: @FreshCode: To answer your question more directly, RAM access is hundreds of times slower than anything happening on the CPU die, so when you have to fetch a value from RAM, there's a good chance you'll incur a massive performance hit, even if only 5% of those accesses proves unnecessary. When writing data, however, the output will usually be buffered in L1 cache, which is on the same die as the CPU core. In any event, if you really want to squeeze the max out of your system, there is no substitute for implementing and comparing both options.

Comment: @Marcelo: Thanks for the complete explanation. I did not realise that setting instead of checking would not necessitate a RAM hit.

Comment: @FreshCode: It *may* not necessitate a RAM hit. A write might fill the cache and force a RAM flush before it can complete. As @Colin points out, intuition is a poor guide in this area. I wasn't being facetious when I suggested that you prove everyone wrong. If you code it up, you might actually surprise us all, due to some peculiarity in the structure of your problem. I would say the chances of that happening are low, however.

Comment: @Marcelo:  Because I have no social life and am a complete nerd, I coded this example up and ran it through the optimizing C# compiler.  Interestingly enough, the "if" instruction is not optimized away -- though the whole code snippet *is* if you don't use the values.

Comment: @Marcelo: I've accepted Dave's answer which better elaborates on pipelining for the time being. You should incorporate the comments discussion into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In C# the answer is: method 2 is always preferred. Since this is a very simple optimisation, if method 1 were really faster, the compiler would do it.

EDIT:

Donald Knuth has some advice against your method 1, such as "premature optimization is the root of all evil" and "code is meant to be read by humans first, and machines second".

Answer (score 1):

This seems like too much of a micro-optimization, I really think the compiler optimizes this bit for you anyway.

But, if you want the final value to be `false` no matter what, I guess simply assigning it to `false` makes more sense. I mean why check if you don't really need to care about the value anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the performance difference is so insignificant just set the thing to false all the time.

If it is false, it will be set to false again.
If it is true, it will be set to false.

At the end of the code the variable will be false regardless.

By just setting it to false all the time you make the intent clearer anyway. Anyone else reading the code will instantly see that the value will be false in all instances by the end of that section of code. While if you have an if statement they will have to think about it a little harder.

For maintenance alone, I would advocate setting the value to false regardless of its original value since it will always be false at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 should be preferred simply because it expresses the same outcome more simply, making it easier to read, as others have said - for something simple like this legibility is far more important than the vanishingly small performance concern.

However, it is possible that `bVariable` could be a property, in which case setting it could entail other side-effects - both in terms of performance and outcome, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to do the comparison is if you have extra logic you need to execute when the value changes.

If you are only going to assign it anyway, it will most likely hurt performance if you do the extra check.

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. There is no way you can persuade me that this "optimization" will give you *any* performance gain at all

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue is not relevant here, because a simple if statement like the above essentially is close to a no-op for the processor. It is much more important that your code is clearly communicating its intention for later readers!

Thomas